# Cutting Overlapping Path (Illustrator CS6)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

i have a problem with a Illustrator CS6, i want to cut overlapping path from my content. I need the path to be over my content (the badge seen in the image) , but not have it overlapping the content. I have the image with actual content removed, i colored the overlapping path red, so it can be seen better. I tried using Pathfinder, but i couldn't figure out how to actually solve the problem.

[image: Badge Example w/ Colored Overlapping Path]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why it didn't work with pathfinder, what happened? Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use that texture effect for the stamp rings only, and have that on a clear, continuous background. Is that right? You're phrasing is a bit hard to understand.

You'll have to make a clipping path out of the stamp, and use the texture as the content being clipped. Duplicate the stamp, and make sure it's a Compound Path first. Also make sure the stamp is above the texture in the Layers panel. Select both items and make a Clipping Path. It should now only appear within the confines of the stamp.

If you want to then subtract it, you can expand the Clipping Path, and subtract it from the original stamp.

When in doubt, copy your items, hide the old ones, and try and bunch of different stuff. You'll get there.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't to it entirely the way you said it, but used the Compound Path Method and used an other Pathfinder, i didn't know the effects of Compound Paths but now do, thank you!